# Laravel: How to subselect two columns from another table in a query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Say I have the following tables:

**event_relationships**

- id
- user_id
- relationship
- primary_event_id
- secondary_event_id

**events**

- id
- user_id
- name
- color

In my user model, I have my relationship setup like:

```
$this->hasMany(EventRelationships::class, 'user_id');
```

And each event relationship belongs to one user.

How can I use Laravel Eloquent to get a list of all the event relationships, but also get each event's name and color? Matching on the `primary_event_id` and `secondary_event_id`.

Is this possible with one query?

Answer (score 0):

In pure eloquent, in the laravel way, that would be :

```
$eventRelationships = EventRelationships::with('primaryEvent', 'secondaryEvent')->get();

foreach($eventRelationships as $eventRelationship){
   $primary_event_name = $eventRelationship->primaryEvent->name;
   $secondary_event_name = $eventRelationship->secondaryEvent->name;
}
```

but it's in 2 queries. If you want only one query, you have to use a join :

```
$eventRelationships = EventRelationships::query()
    ->join('events as primary_events', 'events.id', 'event_relationships.primary_event_id')
    ->join('events as secondary_events', 'events.id', 'event_relationships.secondary_event_id')
    ->select('event_relationships.*', 'primary_events.name as primary_event_name', 'secondary_events.name as secondary_event_name')
    ->get();

foreach($eventRelationships as $eventRelationship){
   $primary_event_name = $eventRelationship->primary_event_name;
   $secondary_event_name = $eventRelationship->secondary_event_name;
}
```

It might be easier to use the first one as you manipulate eloquent object